# how to pass "Type" argument in function?

Tags: powershell

I have 2 pieces of code:

```
# code 1:
[type]$t1 = [switch] 
# all is ok, code works as expected

#code 2:
function test ([type]$t2) {  }
test -t2 [switch]
# here we get error. can't convert from string to system.type
```

I know, I can write: `test -t2 "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter"`, but it's ugly!!
Why can i set [switch] to [type]variable, but can't pass it to function??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
test -t2 "switch"
```

Or you can use the example from code1 and pass in the `$t1` itself:

```
function test ([type]$t2) {  }
[type]$t1 = [switch] 
test -t2 $t1
```

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell lets you can create types with a cast:

```
PS> [type]"switch"

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    SwitchParameter                          System.ValueType
```

What you're actually doing is passing the type name enclosed in brackets:

```
PS> [type]"[switch]"
Cannot convert the "[switch]" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
```

So you need to pass just the name of the type:

```
test -t2 switch
```

or

```
test -t2 ([switch].fullname)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the argument to the test function as an expression and it will return the type:

```
function test ([type]$t2) {  }
test -t2 ([switch])
```